# laravel pagination with search wrong links

Tags: laravel

I am trying to apply laravel pagination with search functionality.

So far I have tried both live search with laravel pagination and that keeps failing and normal search with pagination where I got better results but still not working.

Here is what I last tried for normal search with pagination:

ProjectController:

```
public function index()
{
    $projects = Project::paginate(6);
    return view('dashboard.projects.index',['projects' => $projects]);
}

public function search(Request $request)
{
    $q = $request->input('q');
    if(!empty($q)){
        //dd("search");
        $projects = Project::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q  . "%")->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(6)->setPath('');
        $projects->appends(['q' =>  $request->input('q')]);
        return view ( 'dashboard.projects.index')->with('projects',$projects);
    }
    return redirect('/dashboard/projects/');
}
```

dashboard.projects.index

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row section-primary">
                @foreach($projects as $project)
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 mb-2">
                        <div class="card project h-100">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h4>{{$project->name}}</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <p><strong>Project Manager:</strong> {{$project->manager_name}}</p>
                                <p class="description">{{ substr($project->description, 0,  110) }}...</p>
                                <div class="display-flex">
                                    <div><a href="">View</a></div>
                                    <div><a href="{{url('/dashboard/projects/'. $project->id. '/edit')}}">Edit</a></div>
                                    <div><a href="#">Members</a></div>
                                    <div>
                                        {!!Form::open(['action' => ['ProjectController@destroy', $project->id], 'method' => 'POST','class' => 'form-link'])!!}
                                        {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
                                        {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'button-link'])}}
                                        {!!Form::close()!!}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            {!! $projects->links()!!}
        </div>
```

The code works fine when I go to dashboard/projects and pagination works.
The search works but pagination fails.
When I press the search button it first goes to dashboard/projects/search
Then when I press page 2 button on pagination it goes to dashboard/projects/search?q=project&page=2, here it is requesting the show function which is unrelated.

PS: Any extra help for live search with pagination would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix the problem, for anyone who is facing the same issue, I used in my routes:

```
Route::resource('/dashboard/projects', 'ProjectController');
Route::any('/dashboard/projects/search', 'ProjectController@search');
```

For some reasons, /dashboard/projects/search was not a good idea as it was going to the show defined by resource, all I had to do is change:

```
Route::any('/dashboard/projects/search', 'ProjectController@search');
```

to

```
Route::any('/dashboard/project/search', 'ProjectController@search');
```

so they look like different routes until I find/learn a better solution.

The other solutions is putting the search route first such as:

```
Route::any('/dashboard/projects/search', 'ProjectController@search');    
Route::resource('/dashboard/projects', 'ProjectController');
```

Answer (score 0):

**In larvel => 6 Version:**

Input no longer exists In **larvel 6,7,8** Version. Use Request instead of Input.

Change `$q = $request->input('q');` **to** `$q = $request->q;`

**Your** `ProjectController:`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
..
..
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $q = $request->q;
        if(!empty($q)){
            //dd("search");
            $projects = Project::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q  . "%")->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(6)->setPath('');
            $projects->appends(['q' =>  $request->input('q')]);
            return view ( 'dashboard.projects.index')->with('projects',$projects);
        }
        return redirect('/dashboard/projects/');
    }
```